# Distinct on mouth in linq2sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, razor

I need distinct records by mouth, but I have a error:

> Column "data" does not exist.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Column "data" does not exist.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Column "data" does not exist.

Source Error:

Line 14:     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.dat ,null, "Dates", 8);
Line 15:               }
Line 16: @grid.GetHtml(
Line 17:         tableStyle: "grid",
Line 18:         headerStyle: "head",
```

My Controller:

```
var d = (from b in baza.hours
         where b.userID == userID
         select new { b.data.Month }).Distinct();

            ViewBag.dat = d;
```

And my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        @{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.dat ,null, "Dates", 8);
         }
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
               grid.Column("data","Dates")               

      )
        )

    </fieldset>
}
```

How fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the error that you are receiving.

Comment: my guess is that your column is date not data.. double check your linq

Comment: @PhilKlein I put error.
@BassamMehanni, that isn't a problem :) When I use `b.data` instead `b.data.Month` everything works OK. data is e polish name od date, and column is call data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column("Month", "Dates")
```

You are returning an anonymous object to your view. Or more precisely a collection of anonymous objects each having a property called `Month`. So you should use `Month` as column name in your markup.